# Send message directly to whatsapp (in Background) from html form without being redirected to whatsapp

Tags: javascript, html, api, whatsapp

I created a form as follows:

```
<form> 
<input type="text" id="mssgbox" />
<button onclick="send()> Send </button>
</form>
```

and a script:

```
function send(){
let typedText = document.querySelector('#mssgbox').value;
window.location.href = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=2347034907106?text='+typedText;
}
```

Is there any method i can use to send the Typed text directly to whatsapp (in background) without being redirected to whatsapp!?

If yes, Please How ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it this way. (html & js)
For this, you need to look for the api and implement it in the back-end.
As far as I know, there is no api for regular account. Maybe you can find api for business accounts.

Comment: How can i do that (Api for Business)?

Comment: @Sagmar Read the documentation from this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/